# Stabiliser of a partition

Tags: group-theory, integer-partitions

I'm trying to find the character table of $H$, which is defined as follows:

$$H:= \{\sigma \in S_6 \mid A_i\sigma = A_j \quad \forall i,j\}.$$

Here, $A_i :=\{2i-1,2i\}$ for $i=1,2,3$. In the question, $H$ is also referred as the `stabiliser of the partition $\{1,2\mid\mid 3,4,\mid\mid 5,6\}$'.

I'm not sure if the definition of $H$ makes sense (how can, for example, $A_1\sigma$ be equal to $A_1$, $A_2$ *and* $A_3$?).

I'm guessing that either:

- $\sigma$ maps $A_i$ to $A_i$ for each $i=1,2,3$, or
- $\sigma$ maps $A_i$ to *some* $A_j$, but not necessarily with $j=i$.

Are either of these a standard definition of a `stabiliser of a partition'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that that definition makes no sense.  The intended definition (and standard meaning of "stabilizer of a partition") is your second guess: for each $i$, $\sigma$ maps $A_i$ to $A_j$ for some $j$.  That is, the set $\{\sigma(A_1),\sigma(A_2),\sigma(A_3)\}$ is equal to the set $\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to find the order of $H$. By writing it in two-row notation, I thought it must be 48 (there are 6 choices for where to send 1, then 1 choice, then 4, 1, 2, 1 and the product of these is 48). But I think I've found conjugacy classes of size 9 which doesn't divide 48, and only 36 elements in total. Any ideas? [This makes me wonder... is the stabiliser even necessarily a subgp of $S_6$?

Comment: Your first count looks good to me.  How did you get a conjugacy class of size 9 and only 36 elements?

Comment: I must've made a mistake in the conjugacy classes then. One example was the class of two 2-cycles, (ab)(cd). Two positions are fixed, so they must form one partition $A_i$ (so three choices for $i$). Suppose we fix $\{5,6\}$. Then we have (12)(34), (13)(24) and (14)(23) (three choices) giving 3*3=9 in total?

Comment: Note that $(12)(34)$ is not conjugate to $(13)(24)$: the first one sends each $A_i$ to itself, but the second does not.  (They are conjugate in $S_6$, but not in $H$.)

Comment: Ah, I had mistakenly assumed that conjugacy classes of $H$ were just conjugacy classes of $S$ restricted to $H$. Thanks for your help!